# SICP 1.3 interpreter error unknown identifier: and

Tags: scheme, mit-scheme

I am using the interpreter from browser (without any local setup): [https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs61a/fa14/assets/interpreter/scheme.html](https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Ecs61a/fa14/assets/interpreter/scheme.html)
and getting the following interpreter exception message:

```
SchemeError: unknown identifier: and

Current Eval Stack:
-------------------------
0: and
1: (cond (and (< x y) (< x z)) (sqrt-sum y z))
2: (f 1 2 3)
```

for the following code:

```
; define a procedure that takes three numbers
; as arguments and returns the sum of the squares
; of the two larger numbers

(define (square) (* x x))
(define (sqrt-sum x y) 
  (+ (square x) (square y)))

(define (f x y z)
      (cond (and (< x y) (< x z)) (sqrt-sum y z))
      (cond (and (< y x) (< y z)) (sqrt-sum x z))
      (cond (and (< z y) (< z x)) (sqrt-sum x y)))

(f 1 2 3)
```

I am struggling to find any info about specific Scheme version this interpreter is based on; sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not the correct syntax for `cond`. The syntax is

```
(cond (condition1 value1...)
      (condition2 value2...)
      ...)
```

In your code the first condition should be the expression `(and (< x y) (< x z))`. But you don't have the parentheses around the condition and value. You have just `and` where the condition should be, not `(and (< x y) (< x z))`. Since `and` isn't a variable with a value, you get an error because of that.

The correct syntax is:

```
(define (f x y z)
  (cond ((and (< x y) (< x z)) (sqrt-sum y z))
        ((and (< y x) (< y z)) (sqrt-sum x z))
        ((and (< z y) (< z x)) (sqrt-sum x y))))
```